# Как отслеживать клики на кнопку в Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

Если писать на странице `ga('send', 'event', 'group1', 'click', 'Отслежка');` — ничего не записывается. Кто знает, как правильно нужно отправлять события в Google Analytics?

Answer (score 1):

Так надо

```
$('.add_to_cart_button').bind('click', function() {
    ga('send', 'event', 'cart', 'item-added');
}
```

Comment: где cart это категория  а item-added это ярлык?

Comment: Да. У вас один лишний параметр.

Comment: Собственно, я выдернул кусок рабочего кода с одного из моих сайтов.

Comment: Спасибо надеюсь будет работать, а через какое время там видно что сработало не знаете?

Comment: почему то не работает

Comment: возможно, не те настройки в Google Analytics. Но код 100% рабочий - с сайта, который у меня принял клиент.

Comment: а саму-то аналитику вы подключили на сайте скриптом?

Comment: да подключал, и там есть собвственные цели ->события там прописал и группы  и саму js библиотеку тоже подключал

Comment: А код правильно указан? В консоли что после нажатия на кнопку? Где-то ошибка в другом месте, этот код верный.

Comment: консоли что после нажатия на кнопку?  в каком смысле?
 $('#modal').on('click', function () {
 ga('send', 'event', 'views', 'Открытие формы'); 
})
 вот так все прописано

Comment: Консоль браузера знаете где? )

Comment: вроде да) но просто не понимаю причем тут консоль, там ошибок касательно скриптов нет если речь об этом

Comment: да, я как раз это и хотел узнать

Comment: но все равно не работает (